# It is possible to set the browser tab ID for href target?

Tags: html, browser

We are working on a project which has two websites:

- Company
- Products

When a visitor to the Company website clicks on "Products" we want to open it in its own browser tab.

```
<a href="https://products.example.com" target="products">Products</a>
```

And when a visitor to the Products website clicks on "Company" we want to open it in its own browser tab.

```
<a href="https://company.example.com" target="company">Company</a>
```

The issue we can see with this approach is if someone visits goes Company website > Products website > Company website they'll end up with three tabs:

1. Company (target = ???)
2. Products (target = products)
3. Company (target = company)

How do we set it so the initial tab has a target (in this example "company") assigned to it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to set the name:

```
<script>
window.name = 'company';
</script>
```

*However*, consider that this might not actually be what people want and that maybe you should just let them open links in a new tab themselves.